# Get distinct node values in XML with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I find all the distinct names in my XML by using XSL?

```
<NewDataSet>
  <SearchResult>
    <Name>HAREDIN </Name>
    <Surname>FEIMI</Surname>
    <FathersName>QAMIL</FathersName>
    <Birthdate>1949-06-13T00:00:00+02:00</Birthdate>
    <CustomerSegment>Individe Standart </CustomerSegment>
  </SearchResult>
  <SearchResult>
    <Name>HARMENAK</Name>
    <Surname>BADEJAN</Surname>
    <FathersName>VARAHAN  </FathersName>
    <Birthdate>1943-10-02T00:00:00+02:00</Birthdate>
    <CustomerSegment>Individe Standart </CustomerSegment>
  </SearchResult>
   <SearchResult>
    <Name>HARMENAK</Name>
    <Surname>BADEJAN</Surname>
    <FathersName>VARAHAN  </FathersName>
    <Birthdate>1943-10-02T00:00:00+02:00</Birthdate>
    <CustomerSegment>Individe Standart </CustomerSegment>
  </SearchResult>
</NewDataSet>
```

I wont all the distinct name node, th output like thse:

```
<root>

<Name>HAREDIN </Name>

<Name>HARMENAK</Name>

</root>
```

Comment: Please show what XSL code you have so far. There are countless examples of generic "get distinct values in XSL"-solutions even here on this site. Surely enough to get you started. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[xslt]+distinct

Comment: Can you post a sample of the desired output?

Comment: the output:
<root>
<Name>HARMENAK</Name>
<Name>HAREDIN </Name>
<root>

Comment: Nice job, you've found somebody who did all the thinking and all the work for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kNamesByVal" match="Name" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <t>
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "*/*/Name[generate-id()
             =
              generate-id(key('kNamesByVal', .)[1])
              ]
    "/>
  </t>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document, produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t>
   <Name>HAREDIN </Name>
   <Name>HARMENAK</Name>
</t>
```

**An XSLT 2.0 solution** that doesn't use keys :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>  

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <t>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="*/*/Name" group-by=".">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </t>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Say you wanted to prefix the output with numbers indicating what they are. For example: "#1 - Haredin" then "#2 - Harmenak". Would you know how to do that in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @NessDan, Read about the XPath function `position()`

Comment: I looked into it but it wasn't getting an accurate position in your example. The actual unique nodes in my project are very far apart so I expected `position()` to return things like 1 and 4 (since that's the distance between the unique nodes.)

Comment: @NessDan, This means that you still don't understand how `position()` works. This is a *context-dependent* function and as such it doesn't depend on the actual "distance" between two nodes.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. I'll try it out again once I'm back at work.