# Picking unique heads

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I some XML that is already ordered and grouped by categories. So, I was thinking of using XSLT 1.0 grouping to pull out the category heads. But I was wondering if there is an easier way to simply pick the first heading of each category and group and delete or ignore the duplicates.

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<dataroot>
  <CaseStudies>
    <category>1</category>
    <GroupNo>2</GroupNo>
    <H1>Evaluation and Management</H1>
    <H2>Office or Other Outpatient Services</H2>
    <H3>New Patient</H3>
    <indicators>{+}</indicators>
    <code>99201</code>
    <Fulldesc>Office or other outpatient.</Fulldesc>
    <HTMLdesc>
      <b>Office or other outpatient visit.</b>
    </HTMLdesc>
    <GlobalPeriod>XXX</GlobalPeriod>
    <assist_ref>CPT Assistant Winter</assist_ref>
    <changes_ref>CPT Changes: An Insider&apos;s View 2011, 2013</changes_ref>
    <case_study>Initial office visit.</case_study>
    <pre>Review the medical history.</pre>
    <intra>Obtain a problem focused history.</intra>
    <post>Complete medical record documentation.</post>
    <tip>Levels of E/M service.</tip>
  </CaseStudies>
  <CaseStudies>
    <category>1</category>
    <GroupNo>2</GroupNo>
    <H1>Evaluation and Management</H1>
    <H2>Office or Other Outpatient Services</H2>
    <H3>Established Patient</H3>
    <indicators>{+}</indicators>
    <code>99202</code>
    <Fulldesc>Office or other outpatient visit f.</Fulldesc>
    <HTMLdesc>
      <b>Office or other outpatient visit.</b>
    </HTMLdesc>
    <GlobalPeriod>XXX</GlobalPeriod>
    <assist_ref>CPT Assistant Winter 91:11</assist_ref>
    <changes_ref>CPT Changes</changes_ref>
    <case_study>Initial office visit.</case_study>
    <pre>Review the medical history.</pre>
    <intra>Obtain an expanded problem.</intra>
    <post>Complete medical record documentation.</post>
    <tip>pending proof</tip>
  </CaseStudies>
  <CaseStudies>
    <category>1</category>
    <GroupNo>3</GroupNo>
    <H1>Anesthesia</H1>
    <H2>Intrathoracic</H2>
    <H3>New Patient</H3>
    <indicators>{+}</indicators>
    <code>99203</code>
    <Fulldesc>Office or other outpatient visit.</Fulldesc>
    <HTMLdesc>
      <b>Office or other outpatient visit.</b>
    </HTMLdesc>
    <GlobalPeriod>XXX</GlobalPeriod>
    <assist_ref>CPT Assistant Winter 91:11</assist_ref>
    <changes_ref>CPT Changes: An Insider&apos;s View 2013</changes_ref>
    <case_study>Initial office visit.</case_study>
    <pre>Review the medical history form completed by the patient and vital signs obtained by clinical staff. Communicate with other health care professionals as necessary.</pre>
    <intra>Obtain a detailed history.</intra>
    <post>Complete medical record documentation.</post>
    <tip>pending proof</tip>
  </CaseStudies>
  <CaseStudies>
    <category>1</category>
    <GroupNo>3</GroupNo>
    <H1>Anesthesia</H1>
    <H2>Intrathoracic</H2>
    <H3>Established Patient</H3>
    <indicators>{+}</indicators>
    <code>99203</code>
    <Fulldesc>Office or other outpatient visit.</Fulldesc>
    <HTMLdesc>
      <b>Office or other outpatient visit.</b>
    </HTMLdesc>
    <GlobalPeriod>XXX</GlobalPeriod>
    <assist_ref>CPT Assistant Winter 91:11</assist_ref>
    <changes_ref>CPT Changes: An Insider&apos;s View 2013</changes_ref>
    <case_study>Initial office visit.</case_study>
    <pre>Review the medical history form completed by the patient and vital signs obtained by clinical staff. Communicate with other health care professionals as necessary.</pre>
    <intra>Obtain a detailed history.</post>
    <tip>pending proof</tip>
  </CaseStudies>
</dataroot>
```

Notice there are h1, h2, and h3 heads in my sample but there can also be h4, h5 and h6 heads too.

So, I want to return the content as is but only display each UNIQUE HEAD h1-h6 only once the first time it appears within each section governed by each of the h1, h2, h3, etc.

```
H1 Surgery
  h2 Hospital Inpatient Services
    h3 Subsequent Observation Care
      h4 New Patient
      h4 Existing Patient
h1 Opthamology
  h2 Hospital Observation Services
    h3 Subsequent Observation Care
      h4 New Patient
      h4 Existing Patient
      h4 Subsequent Hospital Care
h1 Anesthesia
  h2 Hospital Observation Services
    h3 Subsequent Observation Care
      h4 New Patient
      h4 Existing Patient
      h4 Subsequent Hospital Care
```

Can this be done without creating a group and key?

I have to use XSLT 1.0

Comment: The heads are always in sequence when they appear.

Comment: **1.** Do you mean you want to display each unique head only the first time it appears *no matter where in the entire document*? **2.** What's wrong with using a key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404675/get-distinct-node-values-in-xml-with-xsl

Comment: Each head will appear multiple times in each category. I only want to display each unique head the first time it appears within its category. I know how to group using keys, is that what you are asking? I don't know how to use keys otherwise.

Comment: I didn't say there was anything wrong with using keys, I was just wondering if there is an easier way. For example, when I write SQL queries I can use the filter "distinctrow" to pull back only unique headings. I'm not aware of any other way to turn off the duplicate heads otherwise using XSLT.

Comment: There is the additional issue of the possibility of having up to 6 heads per item. But I only want to display the FIRST head in any series.

Comment: **1**.You need to clarify what is a "unique head within its category". Do we consider the element's name AND the category AND the text content - or just the the name AND the category? Or something else? **2.** What is "easier" is subjective. IMHO, a key will be the most effective method to use here, in terms of both code clarity and performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that does use a key to retain only unique headings. A heading is considered unique if it is the first of a group of headings grouped by the concatenation of: (1) the element name, (2) the `category` child of the parent `CaseStudies` element, and (3) the value.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="h" match="H1|H2|H3|H4|H5|H6" use="concat(name(), '|', ../category, '|', .)" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="H1|H2|H3|H4|H5|H6">
    <xsl:if test="count(. | key('h', concat(name(), '|', ../category, '|', .))[1]) = 1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to a **simplified and corrected** version of your input example:

```
<dataroot>
   <CaseStudies>
      <category>1</category>
      <H1>Evaluation and Management</H1>
      <H2>Office or Other Outpatient Services</H2>
      <H3>New Patient</H3>
   </CaseStudies>
   <CaseStudies>
      <category>1</category>
      <H1>Evaluation and Management</H1>
      <H2>Office or Other Outpatient Services</H2>
      <H3>Established Patient</H3>
    </CaseStudies>
   <CaseStudies>
      <category>1</category>
      <H1>Anesthesia</H1>
      <H2>Intrathoracic</H2>
      <H3>New Patient</H3>
   </CaseStudies>
   <CaseStudies>
      <category>1</category>
      <H1>Anesthesia</H1>
      <H2>Intrathoracic</H2>
      <H3>Established Patient</H3>
   </CaseStudies>
</dataroot>
```

the following result is obtained:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot>
   <CaseStudies>
      <category>1</category>
      <H1>Evaluation and Management</H1>
      <H2>Office or Other Outpatient Services</H2>
      <H3>New Patient</H3>
   </CaseStudies>
   <CaseStudies>
      <category>1</category>
      <H3>Established Patient</H3>
   </CaseStudies>
   <CaseStudies>
      <category>1</category>
      <H1>Anesthesia</H1>
      <H2>Intrathoracic</H2>
   </CaseStudies>
   <CaseStudies>
      <category>1</category>
   </CaseStudies>
</dataroot>
```

Comment: Or even simpler, get rid of the if by using a no-op template that matches the headings that _aren't_ the first occurrence according to the key, and leave everything else to the identity template.

Comment: @IanRoberts I am not sure I understand your suggestion: the `if` is there to (a) allow matching by explicit element name and (b) avoid repeating the same predicate 6 times.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I forgot that you can't use `(H1|H2|...)[.....]` in a `match` the way you could in a `select`

Comment: I just noticed an error in the XML output. In your sample output the "unique" H3s for New Patient and Established patient for Anathesia are not being displayed. Each heading must be displayed at least ONE time for each H1 head. My instruction may be at fault here. Each heading creates a section. When the H1 changes, each H2 must reset. When the H2 changes, the h3 must reset, and so on. Can the XSL be modified to show unique headings under each superior heading?

Comment: @JimMaivald It's not an error. It's the result of a guess of what your requirement was. A guess I took because you did not respond to my request to "*clarify what is a "unique head within its category"*". In any case, if you understand how the suggested solution works, you should be able to modify it to better fit your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is above my pay grade. I don't understand how you used the key in this instance. Normally, my XML doesn't come grouped and ordered. So, I usually write a key to group and sort data by specific nodes. I've never seen this method before and wouldn't be able to adjust it. Sorry, I didn't reply at the time. I just missed your question.

Comment: @JimMaivald Read about it here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: I'm already familiar with muenchian grouping. I've just never used it the way you did. I'm not a programmer or coder. I try my best and do what I can. But that's why I was asking for help. I have made Muenchian groups for up to three levels, but 6 levels is beyond my skills.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since the input is always in sensible order, all you really have to do is compare the value of each `H*` element to the value of the same named element in the *immediately-preceding* `CaseStudies` element, and suppress any that are the same.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="H1|H2|H3|H4|H5|H6">
    <xsl:if test="not(. = ../preceding-sibling::*[1]/*[name() = name(current())])">
      <xsl:call-template name="ident" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note I'm using `not(x = y)` instead of `x != y` to allow for the fact that there might not *be* a `../preceding-sibling::*[1]` at all.